# Django перевод проект на MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite

Нужно перевести проект с SQLite на MySQL. 
Настройки в settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'NAME': 'django-t',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '1111',
}
```

}

Ошибка "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?"

Понятно, надо установить. Начал устанавливать и не получается. Пытался сделать через wheels - "ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."
Что делать? Windows 10, 64 разрядн.

Comment: А версия Python какая?

Comment: версия питона 3.7.1

Comment: странно, но решил вопрос путем установки mysqlclient-1.4.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl, хотя винда 64

Comment: Значит вы забыли поставить 64-битный питон

Answer (score -1):

У меня сайт на MySQL и стоят такие параметры:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
        },
    }
}
```

Возможно, необходимо будет установить клиент SQL Server.

Но у меня сразу всё работало.. Возможно при установке самого MySQL дополнительные компоненты установились.