# Django не дружит с MySQL

Tags: mysql, django

Все установил, запустил проект, создал бд в MySQL, натсроил пользователья и дал ему права. В сеттингах:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'NAME': 'dtest',
    'USER': 'dtestuser',
    'PASSWORD': '1111',
}}
```

Но Джанго возвращает ошибку при попытке миграции.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)
```

Как с этим справиться? [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926091/django-mysqlclient-backend-produces-django-db-utils-operationalerror-2059-nu?noredirect=1&lq=1) пишут, что нужно изменить настройки MySQL, но я не представляю как? Или проблема в чем-то другом? Как проверить права пользователя бд?

Comment: "Как проверить права пользователя бд" - подключиться через любой доступный mysql-клиент да посмотреть всё что требуется. Есть чувство, что у вас криво установленный mysql

Comment: GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `dtestuser`@`localhost`                |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dtest`.* TO `dtestuser`@`localhost`. возможно криво установлено, потому что с пользователем все ок

Comment: Есть ответ, возможно это твой случай.
Перейди по ссылке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031547/django-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-mysql/1039565#1039565

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031547/django-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-mysql/1039565#1039565 Ответил на вопрос. Посмотри, возможно это твой случай.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По вашей ссылке в посте указано следующее: change the way of encryption of the new version mysql,because django cant support the new encryption.
Возможная у Вас новая версия MySQL? Вот [тут](https://geekquestion.com/6712137-djangodbutilsoperationalerror-2059-plagin-autentifikacii-caching-sha2-password/) описана ваша ошибка и внизу в комментарии есть решение.

Начиная с версии 8.04 MySQL использует caching_sha2_password в качестве плагина аутентификации по умолчанию, где ранее использовался mysql_native_password (что вызывает проблемы совместимости со старыми сервисами, которые ожидают mysql_native_password).